# Chromium appears whenever I start a Flutter application

Tags: flutter, permissions, notifications, chromium

Something weird happens to me lately. Whenever I run my Flutter application for the first time after my Mac starts up, there are two boxes appears asking for chromium permission. I don't have Chromium installed on my Mac, so I don't know where it comes from.

[Chromium permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzsQv.png)

Even if I choose "Not Allowed" option, it would appear the next time I restart my Mac.

Does anyone know why it appears? And how do I remove it?

I run my application on Intellij IDEA Commutiny Edition.

Comment: same to me, don't know how to turn it off

Comment: same issue.. is there a fix?